# Flutter web Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length"

Tags: flutter

I am using this code with flutter web but I get this error on the console,
Refused to set unsafe header "Content-Length"
Please tell me what to do to solve this issue I am using flutter 3.0.0,

```
final blob = html.Blob([bytes]);

final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening when compiling in debug mode:

flutter run -d chrome

Not when compiling in release mode:

flutter run -d chrome --release (or flutter build web)

Except that try:

1. Delete web folder in main directory
2. Run command flutter clean
3. Run command flutter upgrade
4. Run command flutter create .

flutter create .